# Cloudfront with s3. redirect {url}/index.html to {url}/

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am serving HTTP request from Amazon CloudFront using Amazon S3 to store the file. The S3 bucket is set as Website Hosting enabled. The index document is `index.html`.

When I search on Google, I see both these URLs:

- `{url}/index.html`
- `{url}/`

Both of these URLs serve the same content.

How can I set it up such that `{url}/index.html` performs a **code 301 Moved Permanently** to `{url}/`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49082709/redirect-to-index-html-for-s3-subfolder/51218463

Answer (score 2):

Two options, with different levels of complexity:

### Canonical URL

Use a `<link>` tag to tell Google what's the canonical URL for a given document:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/">
```

### Redirect using Lambda@Edge

You can use a simple Lambda function deployed to CloudFront's edge servers. Follow [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html), and the function body you want (Node.js 8.10) is:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const { request } = event.Records[0].cf;
  const isIndex     = request.uri.endsWith('/index.html');

  if (isIndex) {
    const withoutIndex = request.uri.replace(/\/index\.html$/, '');
    callback(null, redirect(withoutIndex));
  } else
    callback(null, request);
};


function redirect(url) {
  return {
    status:            '301',
    statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
    headers: {
      location: [{
        key:    'Location',
        value:  url
      }]
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if it is static content there is no redirect need the way you asked...

You could have config in such a way that if user requests for {url}/  then redirect cloud front to serve {url}/index.html but not other way...

Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html