# Redirect to index.html for S3 subfolder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a domain `example.com`. I have a S3 bucket named `example.com` setup with an `index.html` file that works. Now I like to create two subfolders called `old` and `new`, each containing a separate version of a single page application. Requesting `https://example.com/old` (I like to omit the `index.html` when entering the request in address bar for browser) would open the `index.html` file in the `old` subfolder and requesting `https://example.com/new` would open the `index.html`. What is the best way of doing these redirects? Should I set something up in Route 53 `example.com/old` -> `example.com/old/index.html` or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 82):

No need for a lambda function adding expense and complexity to your project.

The following answer is quoted from [https://stevepapa.com/](https://stevepapa.com/how-to-specify-a-default-root-object-for-static-website-subdirectories-on-aws-cloudfront/)

> `https://stevepapa.com/my-great-new-post/` would be expected to work the same way as: `https://stevepapa.com/my-great-new-post/index.html`
>
> There’s a clever little way to get these flowing through to the Cloudfront distribution, and it involves changing the source origin from the one that Cloudfront presents to you by default.
>
> When selecting the origin source Cloudfront will show you a list of S3 buckets.
> [image: editing origin]
>
> Instead of setting the source from the bucket shown in the dropdown list, you’ll need to grab the static web hosting endpoint for that resource from its S3 settings page and pop it in manually. [image: where the static hosting endpoint url is]
>
> Using the static source for the Cloudfront distribution origin means any request to that distribution will be using the S3’s root object lookup, and your 404 responses should disappear as the references flow through.

### Important

After doing this:

- Clear your browser cache
- [Devalidate the items in your Cloudfront distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html)

Otherwise, the changes you made won't go live immediately.

Comment: Worked for me!!! Thousands of thanks!!!! You saved my day of time because of thi s article.

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Comment: Worked great, this should be marked as answer, so I don't have to read the other stuff on top

Comment: This is the best, simplest answer.

Comment: Would there be a way to achieve the same for `https://stevepapa.com/my-great-new-post` without the trailing `/`?

Comment: This does’t work for me. When I enter the endpoint URL, it puts it back to the bucket name upon bluring the input field.

Comment: @LeonardoRomanello - THis worked without any trailing `/` (it specifically routed `https://example.com/blog` to `https://example.com/blog/` automatically)

Comment: A downside to this approach is that the objects in the S3 bucket must be publicly accessible, otherwise, CloudFront will show a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Using the REST API endpoint is preferred over using the website endpoint as otherwise you have two endpoints with different permissions. These might be indexed twice in web searches and the non-SSL endpoint might be vulnerable to potential attacks. See [the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-restricting-access-to-s3-overview) for more info. Therefore I'd highly recommend [jkingok answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50458087/4185785) which uses the Lambda@Edge approach.

Comment: I was browsing for this solution for days! Thanks!

Comment: That is *so much* better than the official AWS documentation!

Comment: Love you so much!

Comment: this is still legit!

Comment: Manish brought me here... I owe you a beer/coffeee. Thanks mate

Answer (score 21):

So I had this problem last night too.

The issue is as follows:
S3 when configured as a website bucket is forgiving and has the index document setting, set to `index.html` and this gets applied at the root, ie, `example.com` actually gets redirected to `example.com/index.html`, and it also gets applied at the subfolder level, so `example.com/new` or `example.com/new/` should both redirect to `example.com/new/index.html`, where there would be an object in the bucket. (If not, you'd get a `NoSuchKey` error instead.)

However you then "upgrade" yourself to CloudFront, likely for HTTPS, and this feature goes away. CloudFront instead makes explicit API calls to S3 and therefore doesn't trigger the index document concession. It does work for the root, but not for subfolders.

The `RoutingRules` solution doesn't look clean to me because by specifying `KeyPrefixEquals` rather than key exactly equals (which doesn't exist) I think you'd get unintended matches.

I instead have implemented a Lambda@Edge rule that rewrites the request that CloudFront makes to S3 to have a proper key value in it.

Start with the Lambda docs and the A/B testing example here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-general-examples

Change the code to:

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    /*
     * Expand S3 request to have index.html if it ends in /
     */
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    if ((request.uri !== "/") /* Not the root object, which redirects properly */
        && (request.uri.endsWith("/") /* Folder with slash */
            || (request.uri.lastIndexOf(".") < request.uri.lastIndexOf("/")) /* Most likely a folder, it has no extension (heuristic) */
            )) {
        if (request.uri.endsWith("/"))
            request.uri = request.uri.concat("index.html");
        else
            request.uri = request.uri.concat("/index.html");
    }
    callback(null, request);
};
```

And publish it to your CloudFront distribution.

Comment: I had the exact same issue as OP, and this worked! thank you

Comment: Here's an AWS blog post with a similar solution https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/

Answer (score 11):

There is even easier way to accomplish this with an HTML redirect file

1. Create a plain file named my-great-new-post (don't worry there won't be a name conflict with the folder in the same bucket)
2. Write a meta-redirect code in that file (I pasted the code below)
3. upload file to root bucket (where my-great-new-post folder lays)
4. modify metadata of the new file and make Content-Type:text/html

Here lays the content of the file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/my-great-new-post/index.html">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: After a years (read: years) of messing with S3 redirect rules, I'm done. This works best.  "Best" meaning: I do this every few months over years and I appreciate that it "just works".

Comment: Agreed. The documentation on redirect rules is really not great and there are no examples at all.

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution. I appreciate not having to learn what AWS Lambda functions are - let alone how to write them.

Comment: This was the only option that worked for me! Thank you very much for the great workaround

Answer (score 8):

If you're using CloudFront, you can use [CloudFront functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/) to create a simple redirection.

I modified @jkingok's solution.

1. Go to CloudFront, and click on Functions.
2. Click on Create function, enter a name and optional description
3. In the development section, enter the code snippet below and publish from the publish tab.

```js
    function handler(event) {
      var request = event.request;
      if (request.uri !== "/" && (request.uri.endsWith("/") || request.uri.lastIndexOf(".") < request.uri.lastIndexOf("/"))) {
      if (request.uri.endsWith("/")) {
         request.uri = request.uri.concat("index.html");
      } else {
         request.uri = request.uri.concat("/index.html");
      }
     }
      return request;
   }
```

Once your function is completed, you can use the function by going to the "Behaviors" tab of your distribution, select the path pattern you want to modify, then under "Function associations", for Viewer Request, select "CloudFront function" as the function type and then select the function you created in the dropdown list.

[image: Screenshot of Function Associations]

Once you save the Behaviors, you can test your website.

NOTE: This solution redirects every URL without extension to "URL/index.html", you can modify the behaviour of the function to what works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for the root path. Answer from Marc works

Comment: I currently use this and it works for all paths, not sure what you mean by this working for just root path. The only challenge experience so far is that the relative paths fail if the original URL doesn't end with /.

Comment: Works great for me! Thanks a heap - helped me hit a big deadline!

Comment: Thanks for this elegant cross-cutting solution. I found that I could retrieve the security best practices for S3 if I implemented the redirection using this approach. Here is an AWS dev guide with a similar solution https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-add-index.html

Answer (score 3):

When you enable and configure static hosting with S3 you need to access the site via the bucket website endpoint. You can find this URL in the bucket properties in the Static website hosting section.

[image: S3 Static website hosting settings]

The URL of the website endpoint will look like this:

```
http://example-bucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/example-folder/
```

However (confusingly) objects stored in S3 are also accessible via a different URL, this url does not honour the index rules on subfolders. This URL looks like this:

```
https://example-bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/example-folder/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure your Bucket to deliver a static website
2. Create a [CloudFront Distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/): set your bucket as the `Origin` and leave the `OriginPath` empty (default: `/`)
3. Create [Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) RecordSet which links to your [CloudFront Distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)

You can find a helpful walkthrough [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Question: What should happen if your customer enters `example.com` (without `old`/`new`)?

Edit: `2.` is optional. You could also link your Route53 RecordSet to your static website **but** CloudFront enables you to serve your wesbite with `https` (with help of [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/)).

Comment: Thanks. That is the guide that I have followed and that is the setup I have in CloudFront but that doesn't work for `example.com/old` or `example.com/new`. It results in access denied while `example.com/old/index.html` responds with the contents of the `index.html` in the `old` folder. Requesting `example.com` should keep responding with the `index.html` under `example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CDK to create a CloudFrontWebDistribution with an S3 source, then your first guess is probably to do this:

```cs
                OriginConfigs = new[] {
                    new SourceConfiguration {
                        S3OriginSource = new S3OriginConfig
                        {
                            S3BucketSource = bucket
                        }
                        Behaviors = new[] { new Behavior { IsDefaultBehavior = true } }
                    }
                }
```

However, to configure cloudfront to use the website-bucket-url (that does have the behavior to resolve a directory to index.html), you need to use:

```cs
                OriginConfigs = new[] {
                    new SourceConfiguration {
                        CustomOriginSource = new CustomOriginConfig
                        {
                            DomainName = bucket.BucketWebsiteDomainName,
                            OriginProtocolPolicy = OriginProtocolPolicy.HTTP_ONLY
                        },
                        Behaviors = new[] { new Behavior { IsDefaultBehavior = true } }
                    }
                }
```

You need to specify the protocol as HTTP_ONLY because website buckets do not support HTTPS. The default for a CustomOriginSource is HTTPS_ONLY.

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting Redirection rules, Here is an untested rule.

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>old</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>old/index.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>new</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>new/index.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested it but I still end up at access denied rather than the `old/index.html` or `new/index.html`

Comment: This cause too many redirects.