# How to ensure S3 prefixes are same when created from console vs CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

I have the following folder structure that I would like to create in S3,

```
/demo/app/a.txt
```

**Via Console:**

`demo` and `app` using "*Create Folder*", followed by `a.txt` file upload

**Via CLI:**

`aws s3 sync . s3://<my-bucket>/`, where `.` (*current dir*) has `demo` folder

--

Now when I run,

`aws s3 ls s3://<my-bucket> --recursive`, the result is quite interesting/puzzling!

Output:

```
# created & uploaded from console
demo/
demo/app/
demo/app/a.txt

# from CLI
demo/app/a.txt
```

Clearly, there aren't any prefixes/objects for `demo/` and `demo/app/` created using **CLI** upload.

--

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54263794/7245645) helped me understand that "*Create Folder*" from console results in creating a *0-byte* file when the folder is empty. But this isn't the case when uploaded via CLI.

So, how do I mimic the *0-byte* file behavior for CLI uploads? In other words, match the prefixes!

The other use case is, navigating across directories from a browser will not work as the prefixes aren't available. For e.g.

1. Uploaded from console: `https://<domain>/demo/` shows `app` directory.
2. Uploaded from CLI: `https://<domain>/demo/` results in `NoSuchKeyError`

--

*Note: I'm using a `CloudFront` distribution to access S3 data (if that helps)!*

Comment: What happens when you use a trailing forward slash? .. e.g. `aws s3 ls s3://<my-bucket>/` (Note last forward slash)

Comment: @Jamie_D, It's the same output.

Comment: Something you should really understand that while S3 has an appearance (and a confusingly named "create folder" in the UI) of directories, it's actually a flat object store. S3 contains one single item "demo/app/a.txt". "demo" and "app" do not exist on their own.

Comment: You can't do this for CLI uploads. If you really need it (most people don't), then script the upload to create 0-sized objects representing the intermediate folder structure you want.

Comment: @jordanm, completely agree. I just used the notion of "folder" to explain the problem. With the console upload, coz of the presence of 0-byte objects, it gives the impression of hops from `/` to get to `/demo/app/a.txt`, which is sort of helpful while listing on a browser.

Comment: @jarmod, thanks! Could you share a sample script you're referring to? *Note: I wouldn't want to see these (as distinct) files in the bucket; in other words, achieve the exact same thing as done from/by AWS console.*

Comment: @Prathap have provided script in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to have a folder structure present in S3 that mirrors a local folder structure then you could try some variant of the following shell scripting and awscli on Linux or Mac:

1. list all local folders
2. transform that list into something matching S3 naming conventions
3. create a zero byte file at each folder name in S3

List local folders:

```
find . -type d
```

Example output:

```
.
./dogs
./dogs/cute
./dogs/fierce
./cats
./cats/white
./cats/black
```

Transform that list to remove `.` and so that `./dogs/cute` becomes `dogs/cute`:

```
find . -type d | grep -v '^\.$' | sed 's/^\.\///g'
```

Example output:

```
dogs
dogs/cute
dogs/fierce
cats
cats/white
cats/black
```

Finally put it all together and create the zero byte file at each folder:

```
find . -type d \
    | grep -v '^\.$' \
    | sed 's/^\.\///g' \
    | xargs -L 1 -I % \
    aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucket --key %/ --content-length 0
```

Check what this resulted in in S3:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive
```

Results:

```
2020-04-21 21:00:05          0 cats/black/
2020-04-21 21:00:05          0 cats/white/
2020-04-21 21:00:04          0 cats/
2020-04-21 21:00:03          0 dogs/cute/
2020-04-21 21:00:04          0 dogs/fierce/
2020-04-21 21:00:02          0 dogs/
```

Comment: Awesome!! This does exactly what I was expecting; in other words create the 0-length files similar to how S3 console does. Thanks for the detailed answer. Could you explain `xargs -L 1 -I % aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucket --key %/ --content-length 0` part of the answer? I have very little scripting knowledge, sorry!

Comment: You can use xargs to run a given command (`aws s3api`) against a number of lines of input (the desired folder names). xargs takes input from stdin which in this case is the modified find results for folders. The `-L 1` option says use one line (i.e. folder) at a time, and `-I %` means substitute the line content into `%` in the following command. So it executes `aws s3api put-object ...` multiple times, once per folder, and sets the `--key` parameter to `foldername/`.

Comment: Great, thanks again! Going ahead with this answer as the accepted one. However, I must say that the answer provided by @John Rotenstein also achieves the pseudo directory navigation without requiring 0-byte objects. Thanks to both! :)

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 is a flat object-storage system. It is not a filesystem and it does not have the concept of folders or directories. Rather, the `Key` (filename) of an object contains the **full path** of the object.

The easiest way to use S3 is to **pretend that folders exist**, but not actually create them. For example, you could copy a file to S3 like this:

```
aws s3 cp a.txt s3://my-bucket/demo/app/a.txt
```

This will work successfully, even if there is no directory called `demo` or `app`, because **directories/folders do not exist**.

Instead, Amazon S3 provides the concept of a `CommonPrefix`, which you'll see at the bottom of a `ListObjects()` API call. This returns a list of folder-like names that are separated by a **delimiter** (which is normally `/`). This provides programmatic equivalence to a directory, without actually needing them to exist.

If you wish to present a series of hierarchical directories, use the list of `CommonPrefixes` to build that view. This will work even when there are no zero-length files, because S3 looks at the Keys of the objects, not actual directories.

Here's some examples:

```
aws s3 cp a.txt s3://my-bucket/demo/app/a.txt
upload: ./a.txt to s3://my-bucket/demo/app/a.txt                  

aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my-bucket

{
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "demo/app/a.txt",
            "LastModified": "2020-04-22T01:11:20+00:00",
            "ETag": "\"802776735eb3ddcf03962ae47e08ed13\"",
            "Size": 211,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
        }
    ]
}

aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my-bucket --delimiter '/'

{
    "CommonPrefixes": [
        {
            "Prefix": "demo/"
        }
    ]
}

aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket jstack-b --delimiter '/' --prefix 'demo/'
{
    "CommonPrefixes": [
        {
            "Prefix": "demo/app/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice how the commands at the end provide a `delimiter`, so a list of `CommonPrefixes` are returned. This is a way that you could step through a list of directories (that don't exist).

Comment: Oh this is interesting. I believe this might serve the purpose of navigating through prefixes to list in the browser. However, I'll need to try this out as an enhancement, since I have a mixed-mode setup, i.e. files uploaded through CLI & Console, thereby requiring to modify the current logic. Thanks for the detailed answer & possibly the right approach to navigate.