# Next.js: How to make links work with exported sites when hosted on AWS Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to get a prototype Next.js project up by doing a [Static html export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) (i.e. `next export`) and then copying the generated output to AWS S3 and serving it via Cloudfront.

I've got the following two pages in the `/pages` directory:

- `index.tsx`
- `Pricing.tsx`

Then, following along from the [routing doco](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction) I added a `Link` to the pricing page from the index page, like so:

```
<Link href="/Pricing">
  <a>Pricing</a>
</Link>
```

This results in a link that looks like `example.com/Pricing` (when you hover over it and when you click the link, the page does change to the pricing page and the browser shows `example.com/Pricing` in the URL bar).

The problem is, that link is not real - it cannot be bookmarked or navigated to directly via the url bar.

The problem seems to be that when I do a `next export`, Next.js generates a `.html` file for each page, but the router doesn't use those `.html` suffixes.

So when using the site, if the user tries to bookmark `example.com/Pricing`; loading that bookmark later will fail because Cloudfront will return a 404 (because CF only knows about the `.html` file).

I then tried changing my `Link` to look like:

```
<Link href="/Pricing.html">
  <a>Pricing</a>
</Link>
```

That causes the router to use `example.com/Pricing.html` and that works fine with Cloudfront - but it actually causes a 404 during local development (i.e. using `next dev`)!

Other workarounds I could try are renaming all the `.html` files and removing the extension before I upload them to S3 (and make sure they get a `content-type: text/html` header) - or introducing a Cloudfront lambda that does the renaming on the fly when `.html` resources are requested.  I don't really want to do the lambda thing, but the renaming before uploading shouldn't be too difficult.

But it feels like I'm really working uphill here. Am I doing something wrong at a basic level?  How is Next.js linking supposed to work with a static html export?

Next.js version: `9.5.3-canary.23`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Alternate answer if you want your URLs to be "clean" and not have `.html` on the end.

To get Next.js default URL links working properly with S3/Cloudfront, you must configure the "add a trailing slash" option in your `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

As per the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap#adding-a-trailing-slash)

> export pages as index.html files and require trailing slashes, /about becomes /about/index.html and is routable via /about/. This was the default behavior prior to Next.js 9.

So now you can leave your `Link` definition as:

```
<Link href="/Pricing">
  <a>Pricing</a>
</Link>
```

This causes Next.js to do two things:

- use the url `example.com/Pricing/` - note the `/` on the end
- generate each page as `index.html` in it's own directory - e.g. `/Pricing/index.html`

Many HTML servers, in their default configuration, will serve up the `index.html` from inside the matching directory if they see a trailing `/` character in the URL.

S3 will do this also, if you have it set up to serve as a website and **IFF** you access the URL through the [website endpoint, as opposed to the REST endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54263794/924597).

So your Cloudfront distribution origin must be configured as a `Origin type = Custom Origin` pointing at a domain something like `example.com.s3-website.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`, **not** as an `S3 Origin`.

If you have your Cloudfront/S3 mis-configured, when you hit a "trailing slash" style URL - you will probably see your browser download a file of type `binary/octet-stream` containing `0 bytes`.

---

**Edit**: Beware pages with `.` characters, as per [issue 16617](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/16617).

Comment: I'm getting the same error with nextjs 12.1.5 while having all this configured, and now it's throwing a 504 error on any page except the home page. Do you know what might be the cause, is there any other configuration that I should do for the links or the endpoints on that matter?

Comment: Just be aware that if you configure your cloudfront distribution to connect to your s3 bucket via the website endpoint: you will then get charged for traffic between cloudfront and your s3 bucket.

Comment: Thanks. Comments about S3 + Cloudfront are gold.

Answer (score 2):

Followup to [Shorn's self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591611/18574146) of using the `as` field in the next/link component. This worked for me, however it would fail if I refreshed the page I was on.

Instead, I used [exportPathMap](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap) to link my pages to a page.html equivalent that would be created when running `next export`.

The downside of this approach is that when running `next start`, those .html files will not be created or accessible. They will, however, from `next dev`. As I am creating a purely static website, I've now just been using `next dev`.

While making this change I was validating by manually copying my built assets from `next export` into S3 and hosting in CloudFront as Shorn was doing -- I no longer do this to validate and haven't had issues so far.

If anyone knows, let me know what I else may be missing by ignoring `next start` as part of development. This solution has worked for me so far though.

Comment: Neither of these solutions works for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74821870/nextjs-static-build-redirecting-to-home-page-on-reload

Answer (score 1):

To use static pages for nextjs using s3/cloudfront, you need enable website hosting on the s3 bucket. Copy the Bucket website endpoint and paste that as the cloudfront origin. NOTE: you will have to make the s3 bucket public for this to work. Optionally, you can use a header referrer to restrict access to the s3 bucket.
Follow this documentation to see how you can host a static website with bucket endpoints.

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website