# Next.js links aren't working when deployed on Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I deployed my project on Firebase, but the links aren't working as they should be. Locally everything is working fine and paths like `/account` for example work, but when deployed only `/account.html` is working. Why is this? And can I fix this?

I first build my project with:

```
npm run build && npm export
```

Then use:

```
firebase deploy
```

to deploy.

Comment: Have you double checked that you're putting an anchor below the Link component?

E.g. <Link href=""><a><OptionalElement>Link Text</OptionalElement></a></Link>

Comment: @jacobedawson Jep, that was the problem. Only thing is that when you refresh you'll get a 404. I fixed that with cleanUrls from Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

This is late but I had a similar problem and found the below fix worked nicely for firebase too.

Add the below to your `next.config.js`

```
module.exports =   {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

Essentially `next` now generates an `index.html` in a folder for each page and the url now ends with a `/`, e.g. `acmecorp.com/about/`

This has more detail,

([Next.js: How to make links work with exported sites when hosted on AWS Cloudfront?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63591544/next-js-how-to-make-links-work-with-exported-sites-when-hosted-on-aws-cloudfron)

Comment: This worked, but not initially when I deployed. It was because I needed to make all of hrefs have that trailing slash, then it worked great.