# Nextjs routes result in 404 on refresh when hosted on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js

I am a bit baffled by this. Following the simplest Nextjs on AWS S3 demos result in a an app that can only load index.html.

You upload you files to S3. The index.html will load. If you navigate through a link to another route, say `/test`, the page will load. Then hit refresh, and it results in a 404. How can this be fixed? Have anybody seen this before, I am not sure how I got this wrong because I was following pretty basic instructions.

sample demo:
https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-build-a-next-js-static-website-with-aws-s3-643ff55261ac

Note: I have tried this with 4+ demos all with the same result.

Comment: I've not tried this with AWS S3 but this happens when you don't set up rewrite rules for your app, in firebase hosting you set up your page rewrites in `firebase.json` file and looks like aws allows you to configure it as well https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#redirect-requests-object-metadata

Comment: Did you figure this out at all? Could you answer your own question please if you did! Currently stuck on this too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by adding in the Nextjs webpack config

```
trailingSlash: true,
```

I found the answer here: [Next.js: How to make links work with exported sites when hosted on AWS Cloudfront?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63591544/next-js-how-to-make-links-work-with-exported-sites-when-hosted-on-aws-cloudfron/63609112#63609112)

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! If this fixed the issue, maybe mark your own answer as Solution?

Answer (score 0):

With using S3, you'll have to write routing rules to link to other pages. There are a few hacks. [Routing all errors to index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267339/s3-static-website-hosting-route-all-paths-to-index-html). [Create duplicate paths that s3 can understand](https://gist.github.com/rbalicki2/30e8ee5fb5bc2018923a06c5ea5e3ea5).

Caveat: There are many features you'll have to keep working around (not just the ones listed by [Vercel](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features)) that will keep propping up. The folks at [`serverless-nextjs`](https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js#features) wrote many of the features you'd might have to if you stick with S3.