# Nextjs static build redirecting to home page on reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have created a static nextjs build using: `npm run export`.

It is exported successfully but when I'm deploying the build on S3 or any other webserver(apache with .htaccess, Nginx), and serving the index.html when the routes are copy pasted in the browser, they redirect to `/`, and when after reloading when on some route, also get redirected to `/`.

I have tried adding `trailingSlash: true`, still not working and I have also tried:

```
exportPathMap: async function (
        defaultPathMap,
        { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
      ) {
        return {
          '/': { page: '/' },
          '/home': { page: '/home' },
          '/register': { page: '/register' },
          '/login': { page: '/login' },
          '/forgot_password': { page: '/forgot_password' },
        }
      },
```

And still getting redirected to the root. And making the required changes on S3 static Webhosting like adding redirection rules and `index.html` in error is not working.
But all works fine when served on a port on any server but getting this issue only in static build.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I tried the exportPathMap and TrailingSlash solutions but don't work for me neither.

I have fixed it by placing the .htaccess file inside root directory with following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
  
</IfModule>
```

maybe you can find more info here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10522?sort=top